# Language Fallback with Glass Mapper

Tags: glass-mapper, language-fallback

I have two templates that look like the following:

**Article**

- Title : Single Line
- Categories : Multilist

  - Pulls in Another Item that provides a level of taxonomy to these articles.

**Category**

- Title : Single Line
- Description : Multiline
- Image : Image

So the issue is that we have a Article where the language context on the page is `en-GB`, anything on that page that has items with a version in `en-GB` should pull from that language version.  If it doesn't exist in that version it would fall back to `en` language (default language on the site).  That all works correctly except when I have a property in Glass Mapper.

So if I'm on that page and the language context is `en-GB`, but the article falls back (correctly to `en`) but there is an `en-GB` version of the Category which is a property of Glass Model Article.  Instead of pulling the `en-GB` version based on the context of the page, it'll just pull the `en` version because the Article fell back to that language.

**Is there a way to fix this in Glass?**

---

#### Version Information

- Sitecore 8.1-2
- Glass Mapper: 4.0.5.54

Comment: Please specify sitecore and glass versions

Comment: Have you enabled item fallback, or field level fallback, or both?

Comment: Just item fallback

Comment: This might be an issue with Glass, and the way it is inferring language for the linked lookup items. My suggestion would be to log an issue: https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues

Comment: Glass gets the target item using the Language of the original item. https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/blob/master/Source/Glass.Mapper.Sc/DataMappers/SitecoreFieldTypeMapper.cs I believe that in 8.1 this should be en-GB since the OriginalLanguage value would be en. However I would need to check.

Comment: Testing shows this isn't a Glass issue https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues/252

Comment: Hi Michael, hmm that's odd, as a work around currently I'm having recreate the collection in the context language, but maybe there's something wrong about how I'm calling the properties.  I will take a look into this today.  So if I wanted to force the properties to load in the context.language first and not whatever the parent context language is set to, how might I do that?  Is there a way?

Answer (score -1):

I think this is more of an ItemProvider issue than a GlassMapper issue. You may need to write a custom ItemProvider and override the GetItem methods. Although I haven't worked with the LanguageFallback feature provided in Sitecore 8.1, this is what I had to do working with LanguageFallback module before Sitecore released it's official LanguageFallback with 8.1.

Comment: I'm not totally convinced that is true.  So if we weren't using Glass, and instead working with the Item API directly, in this example pulling the articles field "category" would just contain Id's, so at some point something in glass must be converting those ids into items/types.

Comment: @DylanYoung - If you look at the ResolveItem method (Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.SitecoreTypeConfiguration) that loads the lookup field values, you will see that it eventually calls the good old Content API to fetch the item (Database.GetItem()).There is no magic way GlassMapper converts ItemIds to Items. It's all done via Content API, which is why I suggested you look at modifying the ItemProvider itself.